# Get numbers of text with Regex.Split in C#

Tags: c#, regex

How can I get numbers between brackets of this text with regex in C#?
sample text :

> "[1]Ali ahmadi,[2]Mohammad Razavi"
>   result is : 1,2

My C# code is :

```
string result = null;
string[] digits = Regex.Split(Text, @"[\d]");
foreach (string value in digits)
{
    result += value + ",";
}
return result.Substring(0,result.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string s = "[1]Ali ahmadi,[2]Mohammad Razavi";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\[(\d+)\]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(s))
{
  Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

This will *capture* the numbers between brackets `(\d+)`, and store them in the *first* matched group (`Groups[1]`).

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/krR5q)**.

Comment: you beat me to it :) only thing I would add is that should there possibly be and entry like [11] or [342] then you will need to add a + after the \d so that it will match one or more. @"\[(\d+)\]"

Answer (score 0):

Using a Linq-based approach on João's answer:

```
string s = "[1]Ali ahmadi,[2]Mohammad Razavi";
var digits = Regex.Matches(s, @"\[(\d+)\]")
                  .Cast<Match>()
                  .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                  .ToList();
foreach (var match in digits)
{
   Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/iNNIf)